# OS X - always use 4 spaces instead of \t

Tags: macos, system-preferences

I realize that many apps have a preference to set the behavior of the Tab key, but for those that *don't*, is there anything akin to a System Preference that would try to always use 4 spaces instead of `\t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [Tab is a character unto itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_Tab), both in ASCII and Unicode, so unless you tell a piece of software to replace `U+0009` with `U+0020 U+0020 U+0020 U+0020`, the OS will not do so for you. Only a specific piece of software is able to make the determination that this replacement is safe and desireable for whatever purpose.

Comment: The more I thought about it the less I wanted to do it anymore anyway. :) I'm probably dealing with an XY problem, I expect I can find a different solution. Thanks